# NextJS API route gets called once but runs twice

Tags: node.js, sql-server, api, next.js, oauth

I have a page component that hits an API route in the useEffect hook. It appears the API route is only called once as it only appears in the console debug network tab once. However, part of the endpoint script is to insert a row into a database and this row is inserted twice. I only intend for the endpoint to be hit once and the insert to only happen once.

My page hits an API route which passes a code to the MailChimp oAuth flow, this all works and I receive an access token back. I then have another api route which accepts the access token as well as other meta data which inserts it into the database.

Could it be that having one route calling another is causing the problem? I'm not an expert backend developer either so if this is a poor pattern, let me know!

This is my page:

```
import { withPageAuthRequired } from '@auth0/nextjs-auth0';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

const MailChimp = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { code } = router.query;

  useEffect(() => {
    if (code) {
      (async () => {
        const { ok } = await fetch(`/api/oauth/mailchimp?code=${code}`);
        if (!ok) {
          // handle error
        }
      })();
    }
  }, [code, router]);

  return <p>Authorising...</p>;
};

export default MailChimp;

export const getServerSideProps = withPageAuthRequired();
```

This is the `/api/oauth/mailchimp` endpoint file:

```
import { withApiAuthRequired } from '@auth0/nextjs-auth0';
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';

const oauthMailChimp = async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
  try {
    const authorisationCode = req.query.code;

    const formData = new URLSearchParams();
    formData.append('code', authorisationCode as string);
    formData.append('grant_type', 'authorization_code');
    formData.append('client_id', process.env.OAUTH_MAILCHIMP_CLIENT_ID);
    formData.append('client_secret', process.env.OAUTH_MAILCHIMP_CLIENT_SECRET);
    formData.append('redirect_uri', 'https://dev.charity.bi/auth/mailchimp');

    const response = await fetch('https://login.mailchimp.com/oauth2/token', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: formData,
    });
    const { access_token: accessToken, scope } = await response.json();

    // save token in db
    await fetch('https://dev.charity.bi/api/db/authToken/create', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: { cookie: req.headers.cookie },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        sourceId: 4,
        type: 'Bearer',
        accessToken,
        scope,
      }),
    });

    res.send({ message: 'Authorisation complete' });
  } catch (e) {
    console.error('OAuth MailChimp error: ', e);
    res.status(500).send({ error: e });
  }
};

export default withApiAuthRequired(oauthMailChimp);
```

This is the 2nd endpoint file `/api/db/authToken/create` this is called by the previous file:

```
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';
import { withApiAuthRequired, getSession } from '@auth0/nextjs-auth0';
import sql, { MAX } from 'mssql';

import db from '../../../../db';

type TokenData = {
  sourceId: number;
  type: 'Basic' | 'Bearer';
  accessToken: string;
  refreshToken?: string;
  accessTokenExpires?: Date;
  refreshTokenExpires?: Date;
  accountId?: string;
  scope?: string;
};

const insert = async (data: TokenData, organisationId: string) => {
  const {
    sourceId,
    type = 'Bearer',
    accessToken,
    refreshToken,
    accessTokenExpires,
    refreshTokenExpires,
    accountId,
    scope,
  } = data;

  const pool = await sql.connect(db);

  const { recordset } = await pool
    .request()
    .input('orgId', sql.NVarChar(50), organisationId)
    .query(
      'SELECT charity_id FROM [meta].[charity_details] where auth0_organisation_id = @orgId'
    );
  const charityId = recordset[0].charity_id;

  await pool
    .request()
    .input('charityId', sql.Int, charityId)
    .input('sourceId', sql.Int, sourceId)
    .input('type', sql.NVarChar(50), type)
    .input('accessToken', sql.NVarChar(MAX), accessToken)
    .input('refreshToken', sql.NVarChar(MAX), refreshToken)
    .input('accessTokenExpires', sql.DateTime, accessTokenExpires)
    .input('refreshTokenExpires', sql.DateTime, refreshTokenExpires)
    .input('accountId', sql.NVarChar(MAX), accountId)
    .input('scope', sql.NVarChar(MAX), scope).query(`
        INSERT INTO [meta].[auth_token]
          ([charity_id], [source_id], [type], [access_token], [refresh_token], [access_token_expires], [refresh_token_expires], [account_id], [scope]) values
          (@charityId, @sourceId, @type, @accessToken, @refreshToken, @accessTokenExpires, @refreshTokenExpires, @accountId, @scope)
      `);
};

const create = async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
  const data = JSON.parse(req.body);

  const {
    user: { org_id: organisationId },
  } = await getSession(req, res);

  await insert(data, organisationId);

  res.send({ message: 'Tokens saved' });
};

export default withApiAuthRequired(create);
```

Relevant package versions I am using:

```
"@auth0/nextjs-auth0": "^2.4.0",
"mssql": "^9.1.1",
"next": "13.2.4",
"react": "^18.2.0",
```

I am using [mssql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql) as my Microsoft SQL Server client. I'm not the biggest fan but it works and is recommended in the docs as we are using the Azure cloud platform.

I think the error/solution has to be in the API files as the initial call is only triggered once from the browser, according to the network tab.

My current work around is to check if `accessToken` is not `null` before calling the `/api/db/authToken/create` endpoint which works but doesn't solve the underline problem and my concern is if I don't figure it out this will cause issues elsewhere in the application.

Thanks!

Comment: add if (code && router.isReady)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but unfortunately it didn't work

Comment: you can use useCallback for call API